# How to compute a smooth number over a factor base in General Number Field Sieve (GNFS) factoring algorithm?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory, factorization, prime-ideals, unique-factorization-domains

Following [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280463963_A_Guide_to_General_Number_Field_Sieve_for_Integer_Factorization) on page 12, I understand the first steps of the general number field sieve (GNFS) algorithm for factoring as follows:

---

**Step 1:**

Let

$$N = 77$$

and choose

$$m = 4$$

Then

$$N=77 = 1(4^3) + 0(4^2) + 3(4^1) + 1(4^0)$$

so

$$f = x^3 + 3x + 1$$

Let $\alpha$ be any root of this equation, ie. $f(\alpha) = 0$.

---

**Step 2:**

Choose a set of small prime exponents basis

$$p = \{2,3,5,7\}$$

and compute pairs of integers $(i, p)$ where $f(i) = 0 \mod{p}$:

$$\{(2,3),(1,5),(2,5),(4,7)\}$$

Further choose a few prime numbers not already previously included in $p$:

$$q = \{11,13\}$$

and compute pairs of integers $(i, q)$ where $f(i) = 0 \mod{q}$:

$$\{(4,11),(11,13)\}$$

---

I am having trouble **sieving** this in order to get the smooth pair results next, for instance:

$$smoothpair \rightarrow (-10,1)$$

I can verify a smooth number on the integer prime exponents basis

$$ a + bm = -10 + 1(4) = -6 = -2^1 3^1$$

but I don't understand what it means to be smooth number $a+b\alpha$ over the factor base $\{(2,3),(1,5),(2,5),(4,7)\}$?

---

So in summary, the question is **what needs to be calculated to verify** whether

$$-10 + 1(\alpha)$$ is a smooth number over the factor base $\{(2,3),(1,5),(2,5),(4,7)\}$?